# need a little help with translating this fan art

Tags: translation, words, kanji, manga

I mostly understood everything but I'm having trouble understanding/making out three words.

[image]

[image: List item]

the first one is the use of 現場 in this case. I translated it to "scene" or "crime scene" but I'm not 100% sure.

[image]

the second word is ポイント. or rather the kanji the artist used in this case. can't make them out.

[image]

the last one is the word in this speech bubble. here I also have difficulties to make out the kanji. as well.

[image]

I hope you can help me out. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words you're having trouble with are

> 現場、目標地点、軽装

They're not difficult words, so if you didn't have any trouble with the rest of the sentences, I guess I won't need to say more.